# passing input through form and accepting in servlet,redirecting it in Jsp to display result. But i am having some issue

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

> this is my form.

**form10.html**

```
<form method="get" action="./a"><br>
 FirstName: <input type="text" name="txtname"><br>
 LastName:<input type="text" name="txtlast"><br>
Address:<input type="text" name="txtadd"><br>
<input type="submit" value="submit"><br>
 </form>
```

> this is my servlet page

**Process10.java**

```
    PersonBean p1= new PersonBean();

    p1.setfn(req.getParameter("txtname"));
    fn=p1.getfn();
    req.setAttribute("fn", fn);

    p1.setln(req.getParameter("txtlast"));
    ln=p1.getln();
    req.setAttribute("ln", ln);

    p1.setfn(req.getParameter("txtadd"));
    ca=p1.getca();
    req.setAttribute("ca", ca);

req.setAttribute("p",p1);
RequestDispatcher rd=req.getRequestDispatcher("/display10.jsp");
rd.forward(req,res);
}
```

}

> this is my Bean

**PersonBean.java**

```
public PersonBean()
{
    setfn(fn);
    setln(ln);
    setca(ca);
}
public String getfn()
{
    return(fn);
}
public String getln()
{
    return(ln);
}
public String getca()
{
    return(ca);
}

public void setfn(String newfn)
{
    this.fn=newfn;
}
public void setln(String newln)
{
    this.ln=newln;
}
public void setca(String newca)
{
    this.ca=newca;
}
```

}

> this is my Jsp Page

**display10.jsp**

```
<html>
<head><title></title></head><BR>

<body>
<B>Firstname:<%=p1.fn%></b><BR>
<b>Lastname:<%=p1.ln%></b><BR>
<b>Address:<%=p1.ca%></b><BR>

</body>
</html>
```

> this is my Web.xml

**web.xml**

```
<description>
  Servlet and JSP Examples.
</description>
<display-name>Servlet and JSP Examples</display-name>


    <servlet>
  <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>Process10</servlet-class>
   </servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/a</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: what's the issue. Some issue is not correct description.

Comment: probably you should use `Firstname:<%=p.fn%>` instead of `Firstname:<%=p1.fn%>`.

Comment: what ever codes i have wrote in the JSP page it displays the same. i want the information that i have passed in the form to be displayed in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can not access to the attribute on way you wrote it.
If you want to see that value on your page you can us el:

```
${p.fn}
```

Or if you don't like el you can do it like this:

```
<%= request.getAttribute("p").getFn() %>
```

Comment: this code also didnt solved my problem. i think i am having problem with my web server. any ways thnx for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing this but this

```
Firstname:<%=p1.fn%>
Lastname:<%=p1.ln%>
Address:<%=p1.ca%>
```

should be this

```
Firstname:<%=p.fn%>
Lastname:<%=p.ln%>
Address:<%=p.ca%>
```

Comment: it didnt worked. its displays the exact same code as i typed.
like 
firstname:<%=p.fn%>

any ways thnx for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i don't know do you still have a problem. 
But if you have, there is some stuff which i would change.
I would suggest you to change the servlet mapping. (I did not look at you web.xml earlier) But if you check tomcat's web.xml you will see that there is servet with same name already defined.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>fork</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>xpoweredBy</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Next stuff what i would suggest you to change is making package and putting the servlet class inside of that package, and also in web.xml you need to specified full class name not just Process10.
I hope this will help.